# Calling macro right after importing DB from external DB into Excel

Tags: excel, database-connection, vba

I have an Access MyExternTable.mde database which I connect to when the workbook is opened. The Connection is defined by the regular Excel's Data-> connections UI, and works well.
The connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=D:\DataBases\UUUU\MyExternTable.mde;
Mode=ReadWrite;
Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;
Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;
Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;
Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False
```

The commadText is:

```
qryIDNameEXPORT
```

My workbook also contains a VBA `Sub` procedure I called "SortIdNames" which I would like to call right after importing the table, in order to sort it.

Is there any way to call it without using the `Workbook_Open()` or `Workbook_Activate` events?  Maybe something through the connection definition?

Highly appreciate any idea!